# Best parameters for ext4 filesystem to handle virtualbox disk images

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, ext4, large-files

I have ext4 partition, which holds disk image files VirtualBox works with. They all are fixed-size images (i.e. files never change their size). They are defragmented as much as possible (with e4defrag).

I assume that a lot of filesystem features are redundant in this case. I.e. as files are never created, never deleted, never change their size, only reading and "in-place" writing happens, and file contents are aligned on the hard-drive continuously, thus much simpler filesystem could be used in this case (no need for file attributes, directories, journal, etc). Theoretically, I could even use logical volumes instead of files in this case (I am just not sure that I want).

So, questions:

1. How to tune ext4 filesystem, to get best performance in this case?
2. May be another filesystem is more suitable? (Some filesystem that don't support directories, and only continuous fixed-size files?)
   Or may be Linux has a possibility to mount *part* of existing partition as a file? I.e. that I create unformatted partition /dev/sda2 and then

   - mount K-th to L-th bytes of it as /somepath1/somefile1.vdi,
   - mount M-th to N-th bytes of it as /somepath2/file2.vdi,
   - and so on.

Answer (score -1):

1. `mkfs.ext4 -T largefile ...` and never mind about defrag...
2. Use LVM, not a filesystem.

Comment: "mkfs.ext4 -T largefile" This means inode_ratio = 1048576, blocksize = -1. Could you please explain how increasing inode_ratio improves performance and what means "blocksize = -1"? "and never mind about defrag" WAT??? "Use LVM, not a filesystem" Why?

Comment: Mountn your FS/partition whith `noatime` `nodiratime` attributes to increase performance.